# jquery issue , experts advice needed, index not updating

Tags: jquery

I have a few elements in my document, after loading everything I change the positions of some elements using jquery, but the indexes are not updating, As per my knowledge when an element move above another its index should update, is there any command in jquery to update the index after a movement in the document.

thank yo guys

I get the index using `indx = $("#container div").index($('#div_'+id));`
then I change the position of this element ( to above another element by changing the css top value) after this, If i check the index of this element remains same, actually this element is in top position, so I think it index must change

Comment: How/when are you getting the index?  If you're getting it and storing it as a variable, that's a separate thing, and jQuery won't update some variable you've created.

Comment: By index do you mean the tag id or class?  Could you post some code?   Out of interest, this is your 7th javascript/jquery question in a week - did you only get a good answer from one of these questions?

Comment: index means, the value gets using the function index()

Comment: @milan - Can you clarify what you mean by "top position"? How are you changing it's position?

Comment: top position means css, top, I change the position of one element by changing its css top value, now this element is in above another element(div) but its index position is not updating.. Thank you Nick

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3343475/why-my-element-index-is-not-updating-in-my-html-document-jquery-issue here is the web page

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the position in the dom, look at appendTo, prependTo, insertBefore, insertAfter. So instead of moving the actual box on your screen you need to move it in the html like this:

```
<div>
  <div id="1"></div>
  <div id="2"></div>
  <div id="3"></div>
</div>
```

to

```
<div>
  <div id="1"></div>
  <div id="3"></div>
  <div id="2"></div>
</div>
```

Then the index will change